# FB Graph API - Invalid id: 0 when requesting news feed. Profile feed, friends do work

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using ASP.NET / c# to get the news feed of a facebook user. But since today my request for the user's news feed is returning an 500 error. (Internal server error)

Here is what i'm trying to do:
        s

```
tring jsonUrl = graphUrl + "/" + id + "/home?access_token=" + token;
        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(jsonUrl);
```

When i copy paste the jsonurl in my browser i get the following result:

```
"error": {
      "type": "IDInvalidException",
      "message": "Invalid id: 0"
   }
```

If i change "home" to "feed" or "friends", then i do get the result i want. Is there something wrong here?

I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: yes, i have the same problem, i think it has something to do with access_token. When i call same url with access_token from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ then its ok

Comment: I just found this out too. Is it a bug? Because it was working before...

Comment: Yeah, i know, im not sure but i think youve got to subscribe to session change event to obtain new session key...deleting cookies maybe will help you for now...anyway let me know if you find solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "read_stream" to the list of your permissions.

This was working before without adding that flag to your permissions session but now seems they require to specify that.

I was having the same issue in a iOS Application but now is working again